# misplaced overfullrule with itemize and align*

Tags: align, amsmath

Compiling the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\overfullrule=1mm %%% For the draft version
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize} 
  \item
    \begin{align*}
      & Something\ extremely\ long\ and\ boring.\ Something\ extremely\ long\ and\ boring.\\
      & Yet\ another\ boring\ line.\\
      & And\ a\ third\ boring\ line.
    \end{align*}  
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` results in the folowing output:

[image: output of compilation]

Note that the overfull rule (which is typically used for the debugging purposes) is not placed to the right of the last "boring." (as, perhaps, expected) but elsewhere. When looking into the log, you see

```
Overfull \hbox (32.36226pt too wide) detected at line 11
```

This is wrong, too: the overflow occurs at line 8 of the input, not 11.

In fact, this situation occurred in a huge 400-page-long document with a multi-line series of equations and dozens of packages. Originally, I thought that the vertical rectangle was a result of my own typing error or the result of some hacks I had to make to force dozens of packages to live together peacefully (e.g., it could have been a remnant of the suppressed qed symbol). It took me some time to understand that I had a line too wide and that the bar below tried to make this fact visible.

Given the above situation, who is the culprit and how to circumvent the bug?

Comment: There is no culprit: that has to do with the way the content of `align` is set. Nevertheless, the log will tell `Overfull \hbox (7.36223pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--11`. That's usually everything you need.

Comment: The alignment makes a single box and it's this box that's overfull. TeX is correct in pointing at line 11, because it's this line where the alignment is created.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid this answer will not “solve the bug”. There is no bug at all: what happens is a consequence of how TeX works.

1. `align` needs to be able to split its contents across pages on demand (with `\displaybreak` or `\allowdisplaybreaks`).
2. To this purpose, it must use `\halign` at the top level.
3. If you try the following plain TeX code

   ```
   \tabskip=0pt
   \halign{#\hfil&#&\hfil#\cr
     \hbox to 0.5\hsize{\hrulefill}&\qquad&\hbox to 0.5\hsize{\hrulefill}\cr
   }

   \bye
   ```

   you will see *no* `Overfull \hbox` message even though the alignment exceeds the `\hsize` by 2em (the width of `\qquad`).
4. However `align` “knows” that the alignment went beyond the right margin, so, as a help to the user, it makes so that the *last* line of the alignment is marked as overfull. That's as much it can do. The fact that the overfilling is caused by the contents of line 8 is, unfortunately, not available.